# Greasemonkey: To play a sound when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Here's a code of button:

```
      <a href="#" class="lu_button lu_img lb_btn_chart_organisation no_redirect" data-button-id="2" data-issue-id="8568" data-lock-version="1">
        <span class="lu_button_main">Classification</span>
      </a>
```

I want to play a sound when I'm clicking on that button. Can I do that with greasemonkey?

Right now it works but with keyboard and with "Submit" button

```
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xl4r4ocjj8dvtvr/delo-sdelano-delo-sdelano%20%28mp3cut.ru%29.mp3?dl=0';
player.preload = 'auto';

// CTRL+Enter click "Submit" button
(function(){

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13 && e.target.form) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            e.target.form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
        e.target.form.submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        player.play();
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            e.target.form.removeAttribute('target');
        }
    }
}, false);

})();
```

Comment: It takes just a couple of seconds to google the question title and find an example [How can I play a sound within a Greasemonkey script?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27862190)

Comment: @wOxxOm I saw that but it didn't answer on my question how to play this sound when I'm clinking button. If you saw my code, you'll see what it works, but without clinking.

Comment: Use `click` event for the button?

Comment: @wOxxOm @gcampbell trying something like `document.getElementById('lu_form_cancel_btn').addEventListener('click',  function(){
       player.play();})`